# How to insert an normal formula in RMarkdown + Shiny document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, interactive, blend

By watching Matt Dancho´s video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGyHZG6ZqwA&t=310s), I ran into a problem:

I need to insert the simple formula in my RMarkdown + Shiny report, but I´m finding some issues.
First, my .yml looks like:

```
---
title: "RMarkdown + Shiny"
author: "Rodrigo Hermont Ozon"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float: true
runtime: shiny
---
```

Loading the packages I can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(fpp3)
library(fable)
library(tsibble)
library(data.table)
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(shiny)
```

Then I´m using the following datasets:

```
CORN <- getSymbols("CORN", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

BZ_F <- getSymbols("BZ=F", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

CL_F <- getSymbols("CL=F", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

XC_F <- getSymbols("XC=F", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

ZW_F <- getSymbols("ZW=F", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

ZS_F <- getSymbols("ZS=F", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date())

USDBRL_X <- getSymbols("USDBRL=X", auto.assign = FALSE,
                from = "2010-06-09", end = Sys.Date()) # Real effective exchange rate Brazil/Dollar

dataset <- cbind(

CORN,
BZ_F,
CL_F,
XC_F,
ZW_F,
ZS_F,
USDBRL_X

) %>% as.data.table() %>% as_tsibble()
```

Then we can make an interactive dropdown selector for the user:

```
varSelectInput(
    
  inputId = "selectedvar",
  label = "Choose a column from the data:",
  data = dataset[, 
                 colnames(dataset)!= "index" ], # User didn´t select the index 
  selected = "CORN.Close"
  
  )
```

And following I need to input a new RMarkdown chunk can shows me the `periodicity()` of the selected time series, followed for the last 5 days of the quotes of the selected variable using `tail(input$selectedvar)` for example, and so on...

I´m an rookie in Shiny+Rmarkdown and I just want to know if I could use `renderPrint({ paste("The last five prices was: ", tail(input$selectedvar)) })` or other solution to see my desired results that could works well.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The value of `input$selectedvar` is character.  `tail()` needs a symbol.  Programming with tidyverse can be less-than-obvious.  See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for guidance.  The short answer is that `tail( {{ input$selectedvar }} )` should work.  Note that the introductory text should be `"The last five prices were: "`.  Also, please learn how to provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tryed to use @Limey´s solution, but it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

I missed a step.  Apologies.

Here is a MWE:

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectedvar", "Select a column:", choices=names(mtcars)),
  textOutput("values"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$values <- renderPrint({
    paste0(
      "The last five values are: ", 
      paste0(
        mtcars %>% tail(5) %>% pull(!! rlang::sym(input$selectedvar)),
        collapse=", "
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Notice how little of the information you provided is needed to answer your question.  Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to provide a MRE.